# Map recources pre existing and creation

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, map-making

I'm looking for maps of [Pangea Proxima/ Ultima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea_Ultima) that have biomes labeled. As I am basing a world build from them.

Comment: Are you looking for climate zones or mineral resources?

Comment: Remnant, this question may be better viewed, it you asked for good resources relating to historic/pre-historic maps...as it stands this is topically fine but you may want to lay out in a bit more detail exactly what you want to be able to get out of the maps.

Comment: Have you asked earthscience.SE?

Comment: @James Pangea Ultima is not historic. It is what will happen when continents will merge again.

Comment: To the commenters who don't seem to know biomes clarity comes when you do the research. "A biome is a community of plants and animals that have common characteristics for the environment they exist in. They can be found over a range of continents. Biomes are distinct biological communities that have formed in response to a shared physical climate." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general sketch of Pangea Ultima's climate/biomes ([src](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/comments/4l1a5q/climatebiomes_for_pangea_ultima/)):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/khxPz.png

Here is another map I found ([src](http://static4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121029200932/conworld/images/d/da/Pangea_Ultima_-_geographic_map_-_mountains,_deserts_and_rainforests.jpg) (this link came from a pintrest save)):

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/25/b0/a2/25b0a2387bf67d1aa79303e30143e07a.jpg

Comment: Good find, but what is the source of those maps? Make sure to give credit where credit is due.